# How is it I can animate the change in bar tint color of a UINavigationBar but not a UITabBar?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm implementing a theme in my application and I ran into a weird bug (feature?). For some odd reason, I can't use `UIView.animate` in my custom  UITabBarController class to animate a change in color of my UITabBar but the same exact code works perfectly in the custom class of my UINavigationController.

Am I missing something? Is there something else I can use to animate the color change? I've scoured the Apple Documents but found nothing.

Here is the code I'm using in both cases:

```
class customNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    @IBOutlet weak var navBar = ThemeManager.navigationbar

    func dusk(notification: NSNotification) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
            self.navBar?.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 79/255, green: 79/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 1)
            self.navBar?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black

        })
    }
}
```

And:

```
class customTabController: UITabBarController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tab = ThemeManager.tabbar

    func dusk(notification: NSNotification) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
            self.tab?.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 79/255, green: 79/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 1)
            self.tab?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use UIView.transitionWithView to fade between the two states

```
UIView.transitionWithView(self.tab!, duration: 1.0, options: .BeginFromCurrentState | .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.tab!.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 79/255, green: 79/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 1)
        self.tab!.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This didn't have an effect at all on the animation :(

Comment: That's strange, I tried it myself before I posted it. Can you share your code with this implemented?

Comment: It's the same as the second quoted code above. I replaced `UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
            self.tab?.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 79/255, green: 79/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 1)
            self.tab?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        })`

Comment: Sorry I mean can you paste the code with the changes I suggested in it. Or did you fully copy and paste what I said? The two main parts are that you're using UIView. transitionWithView instead of animationWithDuration, and that you have UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve in the options.

Comment: I did exactly what you described and still nothing :(

Comment: You can check it against this test project if you like? https://www.dropbox.com/s/cssorc0z66sqapa/TestTabs.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Well to change color on the tab bar personally I use a whole different image with different colors [image]

As you can see my selected image is my second image. Right now it won't show that image unless I add it to my "User Defined Runtime Attributes"

[image]

Set Keypath to "selectedImage", the type to "Image" and the value to your image that you'd like to display when presented. I hope this answers your question.