# Why won't UICollectionViewCells that are offscreen update?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` displaying custom cells in a horizontal flow layout; in other words, some content is placed outside the screen bounds. 
Additionally, I have a gesture that fires an `NSNotification` leading to a color change of some of the elements of my cells (i.e. a theme). Everything works perfectly except for the fact that the cells that are present out of the bounds of the screen don't all update to the new color change. Is there any way to force them to redraw?

In the function called when the `NSNotification` is fired I've tried redrawing the collection view with `self.collectionView.reloadData()`, `self.collectionView.setNeedsDisplay()` and `self.collectionView.setNeedsLayout` but to no avail. I tried the last two of the list in the `awakeFromNib()` of the custom cell class but nothing.

Here is the code for my `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = popularCollectionView!.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("popular", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PopularPainting
            cell.thumbnail.image = paintings[indexPath.row].paintingImage
            cell.name!.text = paintings[indexPath.row].paintingName
            cell.price!.setTitle(paintings[indexPath.row].paintingPrice, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            if cell.isDark {
                cell.name!.textColor = UIColor(red: 205/255, green: 205/255, blue: 205/255, alpha: 1)
                cell.price!.setTitleColor(self.kPaleBlue, forState: .Normal)
                self.popularCollectionView.reloadData()
            }

            return cell
}
```

Any suggestions?

**Note:** Scrolling to the offscreen content and repeating the gesture to change themes works perfectly so I have no idea what's up.

Comment: Call it in some other thread. Try using `performSelectorOnMainThread:` method for updating.

Comment: @KarthikSivam tried its Swift alternative but that didn't work either

Comment: Please post your `cellForItem:` method code or wherever you updating the color of collection view cells.

Comment: @KarthikSivam updated my question to add the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption that there are cells that exist off-screen for every item in your collection view is incorrect. In fact, table views and collection views re-use cells that get scrolled off-screen for new cells coming on-screen, so there are only ever just over a screenful of cells in existence.

You're right to call `reloadData` after the notification fires. But you need to ensure your implementation of `collectionView:itemForRowAtIndexPath:` will correctly configure cells that are scrolled on-screen subsequently. That will probably mean saving the state change in a property after the notification fires, and checking that property when you configure cells in `collectionView:itemForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I added a BOOL `isDark` to my custom `UICollectionViewCell` and set it as `true` whenever the notification for dark mode is fired. I tested that and it works fine. Then, I tried setting the color of the elements to the dark colors in `collectionView:itemForRowAtIndex` after checking for `cell.isDark` but the application crashes when I add `self.collectioView.reloadData()` with no error in the log. :/

Comment: 1. Do not call `self.collectionView.reloadData()` in `collectionView:itemForRowAtIndex:`. It is already reloading its data. The right place to call `reloadData` is when your notification is received, after you set your `isDark` property.  2. Your `isDark` property should not be on the cell, it should be on your view controller, since it's a single setting that affects _all_ cells. 3. Your `collectionView:itemForRowAtIndex:` method needs also to format the colors if `isDark` is `NO`. So add an `else` block.

Comment: Would you mind answering this if you can? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695969/how-is-it-i-can-animate-the-change-in-bar-tint-color-of-a-uinavigatiobar-but-not

Comment: As of iOS10 at least there is a corner case where cells exist off-screen where cellForItem cannot reach them, but then they sometimes come back on-screen without being recycled. Which makes de-selection for example tricky.

Answer (score 1):

To get around the "view cannot be reached using `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`, but will not be recycled before being shown on-screen" issue, you can move the view initialization logic from `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` to `collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`.

For example, where you originally had:

```
override func collectionView(
    _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
        withReuseIdentifier: self.reuseIdentifier,
        for: indexPath
    )
    // Initialize cell
    return cell
}
```

You can replace it with:

```
override func collectionView(
    _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
        withReuseIdentifier: self.reuseIdentifier,
        for: indexPath
    )
}

override func collectionView(
    _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell,
    forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
) {
    // Initialize cell
}
```

This ensures that if `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` returns `nil`, the cell will be properly initialized by `collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` the next time before it is shown on screen.